# Probability of happening 2 from 3 events

Tags: probability, statistics

This is my second lesson in my statistics class, and I'm trying to understand the following problem:

I have 3 events A,B,C 
$\
Pr(A∩B)=0.25\\
Pr(B∩C)=0.15\\
Pr(A∩C)=0.2\\
Pr(A∩B∩C)=0.08$

And I have to find probability of happening 2 events from A B C (3 events)

My solution:
$\
Pr(A∩B)=Pr(A)Pr(B)\\
Pr(B∩C)=Pr(B)Pr(C)\\
Pr(A∩C)=Pr(A)Pr(C)\\
Pr(A∩B∩C)=Pr(A)Pr(B)Pr(C)\\
=> \\
Pr(A)=Pr(A∩B∩C)/Pr(B)Pr(C)=0.08/0.15=0.53\\
Pr(B)=Pr(A∩B∩C)/Pr(A)Pr(C)=0.008/0.25=0.32\\
Pr(C)=Pr(A∩B∩C)/Pr(A)Pr(B)=0.08/0.2=0.40$

So from here I have Pr(A) Pr(B) and Pr(C), probability of happening two of three events is: $\Pr(D)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)+Pr(c)-Pr(A∩B∩C)$

the problem is at substitution $\Pr(D)=0.53+0.32+0.4-0.08 = 1.25 $

and is wrong from what I know because probability can be a value from [0,1]

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the events are pairwise independent, though this is not stated.  Indeed, it looks like it is not possible for all the events you listed to be independent.

Comment: But if the events are dependent I can't find Pr(A), Pr(B), Pr(C) from formula (ex Pr(A∩B)=P(B)P(A|B) from where i get P(A|B)?)

Comment: As you have discovered, though, the events can not be independent.  The system of equations $ab=.25,\,bc=.15,\,ac=.2,abc=.08$ has no solutions.

Comment: Note:  I am not persuaded that this problem has a well-defined solution.  It could, for example, be the case that both $B,C$ are entirely contained in $A$.  If so the probability of $A$, $B$, and not $C$ would be $.1$ and the probability of $A,C$ and not $B$ would be $.05$...making the answer $.15$.  But other relations between the events are possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Draw a Venn diagram which will reveal to you that
\begin{align}
P(AB) &= P(ABC) + P(ABC^c)\\
P(BC) &= P(ABC) + P(A^cBC)\\
P(AC) &= P(ABC) + P(AB^cC)\\
\end{align}
and since $P(\text{exactly}~2~\text{of}~A,B,C) = P(ABC^c)+P(A^cBC)+ P(AB^cC)$, we have that
$$P(\text{exactly}~2~\text{of}~A,B,C) = P(AB)+P(BC)+P(AC) - \mathbf{3}(PABC).\tag{1}$$
No need to calculate $P(A)$, $P(B)$ etc. or to assume independence.

If you need $P(\text{at least}~2~\text{of}~A,B,C)$, just add $(PABC)$ to the right side of $(1)$ to get 
$$P(\text{at least}~2~\text{of}~A,B,C) = P(AB)+P(BC)+P(AC) - \mathbf{2}(PABC).\tag{2}$$

Comment: why is -2P(ABC)

Comment: Sorry, that should have been a $3P(ABC)$; wtth $2P(ABC)$ we get $P(\text{al least}~2~\text{of}~A,B,C)$.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of two of the three events happening would be

$\Pr(A^c∩B∩C) + Pr(A∩B^c∩C) + Pr(A∩B∩C^c)$,

since the three event are trivially disjoints.

I'm guessing the events are disjoints, making the calculations you made possible.

The result is indeed between 0 and 1, as expected.

Comment: What is A^c B^c and C^c?

Comment: It is the complementary event, i.e. $A^C$ is the event "not $A$". If $S$ is the sample space then $$A^C = \{ x \in S \mid x \notin A\}$$